# Is there a way for me to return my code and do a second def function?

Tags: python, function, random, return

## GUESS THE NUMBER

Just looking for a way to end this function and then do an aimForTarget game with a menu driven program

````
import random

```return guessing```
def guessTheNumber(guessing):


    secretNumber = random.randint(1, 50)

    print('I am thinking of a number between 1 and 50.')

    for guessesTaken in range(1, 10):
        print('Take a guess')
        guess = int(input())

        if guess < secretNumber:
            print('Your guess is too low.')

        elif guess > secretNumber:
            print('Your guess is too high.')

        else:
            break

    if guess == secretNumber:
        print('Good Job! You guessed my number in ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guesses!')

    else:
        print('Game Over. You used up all your tries. ' + str(secretNumber))
````

Comment: How would I make that a "def" function that works? @phungduyphong

Comment: Hi, your requirement is not quite clear, what do you mean by `end` this function, and `aimForTarget` game with `menu driven` program could you be a little bit more specific

Comment: Also I want to introduce you to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, this would help you get your question answer faster, and easier for helpers to follow and understand your problem